# Can we use Swift on iOS7 and below?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I want to develop an app having a deployment target of iOS 6.0. Will it work if I just use Swift, or do I need to write Objective-C code as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No,Swift is not supporting IOS6 and It's support from IOS 7.*.

> Swift is supported on devices running iOS 7 or later.

Answer (score 2):

Swift will only be supported by the devices running on IOS7 or later.A target with IOS6 will not work with swift.

Answer (score -3):

It will work for iOS 7 and onwards. Sorry i am editing my answer.
Because After creating a build, the final IPA file is independent of the programming language (Obj-C/ swift doesn't matter).

For reference, i have developed a test project. And it works.